# Search for values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an array of items:

```
items = [{name: "microphone", cost:1000, improvement:1},
     {name: "guitar", cost:5000, improvement: 10},
     {name: "keyboard", cost: 10000, improvement: 50},
     {name: "band member", cost: 20000, improvement: 100}
    ];
```

And I'd like to find an item's 'improvement' by providing it's name.

I've tried this:

```
var upgrade = items.findOne({ name: nameInput });
```

But I get the error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'buy' TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'findOne'
```

If I can't use `findone` is there an alternative way to achieve my goal?

Comment: `var arr = items.filter(instrument => instrument.name === 'microphone');
var improvement = arr.length ? arr[0].improvement : 'Default value';`

Answer (score 0):

A function like this will let you search for the name inside that array:

```
var findOne = function(arrayOfObjs, searchTerm) {
  var result;
  arrayOfObjs.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.name == searchTerm) {
      result =  item.improvement;
    }
  });
  return result
}

findOne(items, "microphone");
```

Answer (score 0):

> And I'd like to find an item's 'improvement' by providing it's name.

use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method

```
var name = "guitar";
var selectedItem = items.reduce(function(prev, current){

   if ( current.name === name ) {return current;}
   else {return prev;}

});
console.log( selectedItem.improvement );
```

Comment: @Tushar thanks, but I am using reduce method now, since find is not very well supported on most browsers today

Comment: The console log result is 'undefined'

Comment: @chendriksen no it isn't, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/noonzo2L/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  items = [{name: "microphone", cost:1000, improvement:1},
         {name: "guitar", cost:5000, improvement: 10},
         {name: "keyboard", cost: 10000, improvement: 50},
         {name: "band member", cost: 20000, improvement: 100}
        ];
```

if your item name is:

```
itemname = "microphone";    
    items.forEach(function(obj) {
        if(obj.name == itemname){
         return obj.improvement;
        }
    });
```